# lowering output level of a phono preamp

Tags: audio, preamp, level

I built a RIAA phono preamp that works great from these schematics:
[image]

But the output level seems a bit too high. What would be the best way to lower it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to use a resistive divider in the output.  Alternatively you could increase R5,11 and decrease C2,10 in proportion.

Comment: Changing the value of R6,12 somehow adds a RC lowpass filter to the output..
And increasing R5,11 would reduce the input volume which is probably not desirable due to the already low levels of a phone cartridge.

Comment: Ok, I think you meant adding a 100k to ground to divide the output by 2 for example?

Comment: No, split R6 into two resistors in series. Take the output from the junction of the two resistors. Make the total resistance about 10k so that you have a reasonably low output impedance. (It's 100k as shown so that the capacitor is discharged so you don't get a DC thump when you plug it into the amplifier.) When you say "the output seems a bit high" do you mean relative to the other sources such as CD and radio? It's generally the higher the better as far as signal to noise ratio goes.

Comment: Replace R6 and R12 with preset potentiometers and take the output from the wiper. Then you can adjust them to match the other sources if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I replaced R6 and R12 by 2 resistive dividers of 5k1 and 6k2 to ground, by my understanding getting 55/60% of the signal, perfectly filling my need to adjust to my other RIAA preamp on my DIY mixer. Thank you!